# What is the value of Exponential Geometric Sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The sum in question is 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{a^k}. $$
This comes from a more difficult summation, but if I can find the value of this one then the other one is solved.

Does anyone know the exact value of this? Any help in that direction would be really appreciated.

---

The original problem is in this post: [A tricky infinite sum-- solution found numerically, need proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620700/a-tricky-infinite-sum-solution-found-numerically-need-proof/621323#621323)

$X Y^{\alpha} + X^2 Y^{\alpha + \alpha^2} +X^3 Y^{\alpha + \alpha^2 + \alpha^3} + ...=\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{\infty}X^j \prod\limits_{k = 1}^{j}Y^{\alpha^k}$
where $0 < \alpha < 1, 0 < X < 1$ and $Y>0$

Comment: I'm afraid not. All that's clear is that, in order for the sum to be convergent, $|x|<1$. Perhaps putting up the original question would be more useful ?

Comment: It would definitely help if you put up the original question.

Comment: There it is. @Mike

Comment: It looks as if my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664438/summation-evaluation-of-sum-j-0k-n1-2j/664717#664717 might match your problem. If it is so, and the approach meets your needs in principle then it might be adapted/refined if needed/if possible.

Comment: Also you might google for "lacunary series".

Comment: The only thing that comes close is the [Jacobi theta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Nine years too late !*

As @Gottfried Helms answered, there is no closed form for

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{a^k}$$
But, the corresponding integral exists
$$T=\int_{0}^\infty x^{a^k}\,dk=-\frac{\text{Ei}(\log (x))}{\log (a)}$$
where appears the exponential integral function.

In order to obtain some approximation, consider using Euler-MacLaurin summation formula at one of its lowest levels.

Using $\alpha=\log(a)$, it should give
$$S \sim \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\text{li}(x)}{\alpha}\right)-\frac{\alpha \, x\,\log(x)}{239500800}\sum_{n=0 }^8 P_n(\alpha)\,\log^n(x)$$ with
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n(\alpha) \\
 0 & 5 \alpha ^8-198 \alpha ^6+7920 \alpha ^4-332640 \alpha
   ^2+19958400 \\
 1 & 3 \alpha ^2 \left(425 \alpha ^6-4158 \alpha ^4+39600 \alpha
   ^2-332640\right) \\
 2 & 11 \alpha ^2 \left(1375 \alpha ^6-5418 \alpha ^4+18000 \alpha
   ^2-30240\right) \\
 3 & 150 \alpha ^4 \left(259 \alpha ^4-462 \alpha ^2+528\right) \\
 4 & 15 \alpha ^4 \left(2317 \alpha ^4-1848 \alpha ^2+528\right)
   \\
 5 & 378 \alpha ^6 \left(35 \alpha ^2-11\right) \\
 6 & 66 \alpha ^6 \left(35 \alpha ^2-3\right) \\
 7 & 180 \alpha ^8 \\
 8 & 5 \alpha ^8 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using $a=\pi$ and $x=\frac 34$, the above formula gives
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{\pi ^k}\sim 1.21393$$ while the summation gives $1.21364$ (relative error of $0.025$%).

Be sure that we can do much better useing more terms for the Euler-MacLaurin summation.

Comment: Very nice Claude! Unfortunately I'm in the 70'ies now and a bit too worn out to be able to engage creatively... I had a nice turn the last 16 years, and especially often liked your cool ideas, btw. :-)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms. Young man ! I am 81. Cheers :-)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms. Funny thing in your profile : I also enjoy (like, lov,..) reading Euler's and Lambert's paper in Latin. So great men !!

Comment: Uff, 81! :-) A trinity in four dimensions - this is really cool. Perhaps I should take some refresh in one of your senior-senior-senior-classes. Our "master of us all" has been productive up to his old age (don't know it numerically) ... Well, some so and some so ... :-)  - - -  Ah, ps. did you ever see my Euler-MacLaurin-reenginering? It's about 10 years old but I still find it a special amazing piece.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no general closed expression for this. The problem is known with the keyword "lacunary series", and there is an informative [wikipedia-page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function) about this.

Comment: Just for the fun, I added something. Cheers :-)